# Facebook like page button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm working on project (http://www.aladebauche.com) and need to add a like/share button that point to a FaceBook page https://www.facebook.com/ALDBCH/.

I follow the common way to create a like button by going to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button and put the FB page link in the URL field, but when focusing out the field nothing appear in the preview field, this occurs on every FB Page i put there, i'm missing something very simple i suppose but it's very annoying..

PS : i dont want to use the Plugin page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) because the output is ugly and will disfigure my landing page.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems Facebook is having some cache issues, playing around with some buttons generators (share, follow etc..) i succeeded to create my share/like buttons again, very weird.